# Invariance of a Bell state under local unitary transformations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

How can I show explicitly that the Bell state

$$|\psi^{-} \rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle |1\rangle - |1\rangle |0\rangle)$$

is *invariant under local unitary transformations $U_{1}\otimes U_{2}$*?

Comment: It is not invariant: Try $U_{1}\otimes U_{2} = \sigma_x \otimes \mathbb{Id}$

Comment: I think that you meant that it is invariant  (up to a phase) under $U\otimes U$ in which the same unitary transformation is performed on each qubit separately, right? That's true because $U\otimes U$ is the action of an $SU(2)$ rotation and the singlet state is invariant under the total $SU(2)$, the group generated by the total angular momentum. But it is not invariant under the $SU(2)_1$ and $SU(2)_2$ groups separately. For example, a rotation of the first qubit only, a la Trimok, gives you states like $00+11$ etc.

Comment: For demonstration by "brute force", you may use that a unitary operator $U$ of $U(2)$has the form: $U = e^{i\alpha} S$, where $\alpha$ is a real.
and $S$ belongs to $SU(2)$

$S$ can be written
$S =  e^{i~\theta~ \vec n.\vec \sigma} =  (cos \theta  ~\mathbb{Id} + i sin\theta~\vec n.\vec \sigma)$, where $\theta$ is a real, $\vec n$ is a normed vector ($(\vec n)^2 = 1$), and $\vec \sigma$ are the Pauli matrices.    

And you have : 

$S|0> = (cos \theta + i sin\theta~n^z)|0> + i sin\theta(~n^x + in^y)|1>$, $S|1> = i sin\theta(~n^x - in^y) |0> + (cos \theta - i sin\theta~n^z) |1>$